# Transforming a sentence into passive report without using the object

Tags: passive-voice

How do I transform the sentence "People say there has been an accident" into passive report to a "X is said to..." form without using "an accident" in the beginning? The criteria are weird and are really giving me trouble since I can't think of anything that meets them.

Comment: _There is said to have been an accident_. You can't do it with a _that_ complement, but an infinitive allows Raising of _there_ to be the subject, leaving the accident to be encountered at the end.

Comment: "An accident" is not an object, so the clause  can't be passivised. As JL says, you can have "There is said to have been an accident", which is passive, but it's not the passive equivalent of your example.

Comment: How about "People are heard to say that there has been an accident"? That's passive and 'accident' is only a part of the noun phrase which forms the object.